# How to compute the series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Trying to prove 
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty{\frac{\left(1+(-1)^k\right) \sqrt{\pi }\,\Gamma\left[\frac{1+k}{2}\right]}{k^2 \Gamma\left[\frac{k}{2}\right]}}=\pi \log(2)$$
How to do that? Some clues?

Comment: The term $1+(-1)^k$ vanishes when $k$ is odd so you only sum over even $k$. You can look up precise formulas for the Gamma function.

Comment: Which formulas you mean?

Answer (score 2):

The odd terms vanish. Hence, we get
$$S = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{2 \sqrt{\pi} \Gamma((2k+1)/2)}{(2k)^2 \Gamma(k)}$$
We have
$$\Gamma(k+1/2) = (k-1/2)(k-3/2) \cdots 1/2 \times \sqrt{\pi} = \dfrac{(2k-1)!!}{2^k} \sqrt{\pi} = \dfrac{(2k)!}{4^k \cdot k!} \sqrt{\pi}$$
We hence have
$$S = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{2 \pi (2k)!}{4^k \cdot k! (k-1)!(2k)^2} = 2\pi \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dbinom{2k}{k} \dfrac{4^{-k-1}}k$$
Recall that
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dbinom{2k}k \dfrac{x^k}k = 2 \log(2) - 2 \log(1+\sqrt{1-4x})$$ There are many ways to obtain the above. One way is to write the Taylor series of $\log(1+\sqrt{1-4x})$ about $x=0$. We hence get that
$$S = \dfrac{2 \pi}4\left(2 \log(2) - 2 \log \left(1+\sqrt{1-4 \cdot 1/4} \right)\right) = \pi \log(2)$$

Comment: How do you get $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dbinom{2k}k \dfrac{x^k}k = 2 \log(2) - 2 \log(1+\sqrt{1-4x})$? It's not clear to me yet.

Comment: @Porky As I said in the post, there are many ways to do it. Write the Taylor series for $\log(1+\sqrt{1-4x})$ or write the Taylor series for $\dfrac1x\left(\dfrac1{\sqrt{1-4x}}-1 \right)$ and integrate it term by